# bison.exe cannot find file m4sugar.m4 which is required by an MSBuild in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, msbuild, bison, qgis

I am trying to compile QGIS in Visual Studio.  I used OSGeo4W to download the packages, added Flex.exe and Bison.exe to my environment path.  Downloaded QGIS Release 2.0, and launched a CMake-GUI with the option "Visual Studio 10".  Then I configured my paths using the GUI tool.

[image: CMakeGui1]
[image: CMakeGui2]
[image: CMakeGui3]

Then I hit configure and generate, and it worked.  I looked in my directory and there were Visual Studio Solution files available for me.  Then I hit "Build All" and I got the following output in the "Output Window"

```
Generating flex_qgsexpressionlexer.cpp
Generating qgsexpressionparser.cpp 1>  C:\OSGeo4W\bin\bison.exe: cannot open file
`C:\OSGeo4W/share/bison/m4sugar/m4sugar.m4': No such file or directory
```

So this is where I am stuck.  The first thing I tried was to download m4sugar.m4, which I found [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/autoconf/autoconf-10/autoconf/m4sugar.m4) -- I didn't really think it would work since I downloaded it from apple.com, but I thought it was worth a shot, I put it in the correct directory, and hit build... This time it displayed
`Generating qgsexpressionparser.cpp` but it just stalled there and wasn't able to give anymore output.

After doing some reading I got the impression that m4sugar.m4 is somehow not a standard file and that you need to use it while running msys or cygwin.  So then I tried to do my Visual Studio Build with MSys but I was unable to run vcvars32.bat.  Maybe I should try harder with that approach?  Anyway to get this m4 file working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I was lazy.

I wanted to save time so i just copied the bison.exe to my c:\osgeo4w\bin with was already set in my %PATH%.  And it requires all these other files.  So I changed the path in my CMake-GUI to point to the actual Bison.exe with access to the appropriate relative paths, and I made sure that it wasn't in a directory with spaces, and then reconfigured my CMake-GUI and regenerated my project, and its working now.